# Does jOOQ support putting names on SQL statements?

Tags: amazon-rds, jooq

Is there a way to "tag" or put names on SQL statements in jOOQ so when I look at the Performance Insights of AWS RDS, I can see something more meaningful than the first 500 chars of the statement?

For example, Performance Insights shows that this query is taking a toll in my DB:

> select "my_schema"."custs"."id", "my_schema"."custs"."other_id", "my_schema"."custs"."cid_id", "my_schema"."custs"."valid_since", "my_schema"."custs"."valid_until", "my_schema"."custs"."address", "my_schema"."custs"."address_id_1", "my_schema"."pets"."id", "my_schema"."pets"."cst_id", "my_schema"."pets"."tag", "my_schema"."pets"."name", "my_schema"."pets"."description", "my_schema"."pets"."owner", "my_schema"."pets"."created_on", "my_schema"."pets"."created_by", "my_schema"."pets"."modified_on",

But as it comes chopped, it's not straight-forward to know which jOOQ code generated this.

I would prefer to see something like this:

> Customer - Pet Lookup

or:

> (Customer - Pet Lookup) select "my_schema"."custs"."id", "my_schema"."custs"."other_id", "my_schema"."custs"."cid_id", "my_schema"."custs"."valid_since", "my_schema"."custs"."valid_until", "my_schema"."custs"."address", "my_schema"."custs"."address_id_1", "my_schema"."pets"."id", "my_schema"."pets"."cst_id", "my_schema"."pets"."tag", "my_schema"."pets"."name", "my_schema"."pets"."description", "my_schema"."pets"."owner", "my_schema"."pets"."created_on", "my_schema"."pets"."created_by", "my_schema"."pets"."modified_on",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two out of the box approaches to what you want to achieve, both completely vendor agnostic:

#### 1. Use "hints"

jOOQ supports Oracle style hints using the `hint()` method, at least for `SELECT` statements. Write something like:

```java
ctx.select(T.A, T.B)
   .hint("/* my tag */")
   .from(T)
   .where(...)
```

The limitation here is the location of the hint, which is going to be right after the `SELECT` keyword. Not sure if this will work for your RDBMS.

#### 2. Use an `ExecuteListener`

You can supply your [`Configuration`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Configuration.html) with an [`ExecuteListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html), which patches your generated SQL strings with whatever you need to be added:

```java
class MyListener extends DefaultExecuteListener {

    // renderEnd() is called after the SQL string is generated, but
    // before the prepared statement is created, let alone executed
    @Override
    public void renderEnd​(ExecuteContext ctx) {
        if (mechanismToDetermineIfTaggingIsNeeded())
            ctx.sql("/* My tag */ " + ctx.sql());
    }
}
```

Using regular expressions, you can place that tag at any specific location within your SQL string.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give them a try and report back